# http request with Devise Login

Tags: iphone, http, devise, request

This is a really nooby-question. I wanna link my iphone app with a devise login on an existing site. the existing scripts shouldnt be changed, there should be a simple 'interface' between the app and the site. (php?) is it possible to do it this way:

http://www.mysite.com/login.php?username=name&password=password&auth=token

how should this login.php look like to connect my app with the devise on the website?

i want to get back "true" if the user exists and "false" if the userdata is wrong.

is there a easy way to implement this?

thanks for your patience and help ;)

Comment: You would need an API to handle these requests better.

Comment: do you know if there is already an existing api out there? you mean API to fill the gap between the devise and the app, am I right? this could be an php-script, that get the data from the app and send it to the devise? do you know an example how this could look like? thanks so much again for your time.

Comment: I mean an api which returns the result from your server either in `XML` or `JSON` format so you can parse and display the data in your app.

Comment: is this possible without changing the existing devise code? how could this api look like? sorry, i'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Here's an example of API with results in JSON: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true` and for xml: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true`

Comment: ok, i understand about the result. but i think i need an interface between my POST/GET method in my app and the devise scripts on the server. thats exactly what i dont get: how to get in contact with the devise via post/get like in my first post. some (hopefully simple php) script that does the 'translation' between the app and the devise. how could a script like this look like?

Answer (score 0):

http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise

Use token_authentication with devise. This allows you to access resources using an auth token. You might need some sort of authorisation such as CanCan.

Comment: isnt it possible to forward login data with a simple php to the devise web interface? sorry, I've no idea about ruby and no direct access to the web server, so i cant change/add some code in the devise scripts.

Comment: Yes, but it's potentially much more complicated to do this. You can load the login page, and send a POST NSURLRequest containing the information your login form needs. But then you'd have to traverse the DOM of the resulting page. Why not write an api namespace in your routes and make it only available to certain users?

Comment: The main problem is: with my tool I'm creating apps the only way i'm able to get and send data from the web is by using "http://www.mysite.com/login?username=name&password=pw&auth=token", but how i could do an api? how should this look like? what's the easiest way?